# by-and-by: meaning in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It seems that in this context "by-and-by" doesn't mean "before long" or something of the kind.
It's an extract from Meredith's *Diana of the Crossways*. I'd be grateful if you could explain what it means; my only guess is that it is something like "your health" because the characters are about to drink champagne. Thanks in advance!

> 'I'll never live to hear a lady insulted.'
>
> 'You don't mean to say you're the donkey to provoke a duel!' Mr.
>   Redworth burst out gruffly, through turkey and stuffing.
>
> 'And an Irish lady, the young Beauty of Erin!' Mr. Sullivan Smith was
>   flowing on. He became frigid, he politely bowed: 'Two, sir, if you
>   haven't the grace to withdraw the offensive term before it cools and
>   can't be obliterated.'
>
> 'Fiddle! and go to the deuce!' Mr. Redworth cried.
>
> 'Would a soft slap o' the cheek persuade you, sir?'
>
> 'Try it outside, and don't bother me with nonsense of that sort at my
>   supper. If I'm struck, I strike back. I keep my pistols for bandits
>   and law-breakers. Here,' said Mr. Redworth, better inspired as to the
>   way of treating an ultra of the isle; 'touch glasses: you're a
>   gentleman, and won't disturb good company. **By-and-by**.'
>
> The pleasing prospect of **by-and-by** renewed in Mr. Sullivan Smith
>   his composure. They touched the foaming glasses: upon which, in a
>   friendly manner, Mr. Sullivan Smith proposed that they should go
>   outside as soon as Mr. Redworth had finished supper-quite finished
>   supper: for the reason that the term 'donkey' affixed to him was like
>   a minster cap of schooldays, ringing bells on his topknot, and also
>   that it stuck in his gizzard.

Comment: I strongly suspect it *does* mean before long. The characters have agreed to duel by and by: as soon as they finish the meal.

Comment: The first quoted use is not consistent with the current idiomatic meaning.  It almost sounds like a toast.  The second use is slightly more consistent with current meaning, but still not totally idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

I think it means "eventually" in the first instance, and is used as a noun in the second:

***[By and by](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/by+and+by)***

> - adverb - ***presently or eventually***
>     n
> - noun -  US and Canadian a future time or occasion
>     Collins English Dictionary –